# Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandManagerInterface

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5

I'm getting Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandManagerInterface when adding in custom Api/Model class constructor

Error is showing for this class interface only rests are working fine.

Magento version 2.4.5

already did:-
rm -rf generated
bin/magento s:up
bin/magento s:di:c
bin/magento s:s:d -f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering typically occurs when you attempt to instantiate an interface directly. Interfaces cannot be instantiated directly because they define a contract for classes to implement, but they do not provide concrete implementations themselves.

To resolve this issue, you should not try to instantiate the interface Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandManagerInterface directly. Instead, you need to inject an instance of the class that implements this interface into your custom API/Model class constructor.

Here's an example of how you can inject the CommandManagerInterface into your class constructor:

```
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandManagerInterface;

class YourCustomClass
{
    protected $commandManager;

    public function __construct(
        CommandManagerInterface $commandManager
    ) {
        $this->commandManager = $commandManager;
    }

    // Your class methods...
}
```

Update your module's di.xml file to provide the implementation of the interface:

```
<config>
    <preference for="Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandManagerInterface" 
                type="Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandManager" />
</config>
```

After making these changes, Magento's dependency injection system will automatically provide an instance of the Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandManager class that implements the Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandManagerInterface interface.

Remember to recompile, clean generated files, and flush the cache after making changes to ensure that the changes take effect.

Comment: Thanks @Charmi Patel